# Как по кнопке, один див поменять другим

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

```css
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-image: url(background.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
.header {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 0%;
}
.container {
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.outer {
    
    background-image: url("background.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;

}
.main {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
}
.container2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 450px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.container3 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 450px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.discorddontclick1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 50px;
    
}
.discorddontclick2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.discorddontclick3 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.dslogo {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-image: url(dsLogo.png);
    margin-left: 25px;
}
.serverlogo {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-image: url(severlogo.png);
    margin-left: 25px;
}
.sociallogo {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-image: url(sociallogo.png);
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.text1 {
    display: block;
    width: 253px;
    height: 31px;
    margin-left: 23.5px;
}

.ds {
    display: flex;
    color: aliceblue;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Joan', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 0;
}
.text2 {
    display: block;
    width: 274px;
    height: 31px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.servera {
    display: flex;
    color: aliceblue;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Joan', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.text3 {
    display: block;
    width: 178px;
    height: 31px;
    margin-left: 61px;
    text-align: center;
}

.medialink {
    display: flex;
    color: aliceblue;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Joan', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.buttongradient {
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    background-image: url(gradient.png);
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.moreinf1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Joan', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 39px;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    text-align: center;
    color: aliceblue;
}
.buttongradient2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    background-image: url(gradient.png);
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.moreinf2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Joan', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 39px;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    text-align: center;
    color: aliceblue;
}
.buttongradient3 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    background-image: url(gradient.png);
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.moreinf3 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Joan', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 39px;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    text-align: center;
    color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Destiny Project</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Joan&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="page1.html">
                <img src="logo1.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="container2">
            <div class="container3">
                <div class="discorddontclick1">
                    <div class="dslogo"></div>
                    <div class="text1">
                        <p class="ds">Наши Discord сервера</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttongradient">
                        <button class="moreinf1">Подробнее</button>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="discorddontclick2">
                    <div class="serverlogo"></div>
                    <div class="text2">
                        <p class="servera">Наши игровые сервера</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttongradient2">
                        <button class="moreinf2">Подробнее</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="discorddontclick3">
                    <div class="sociallogo"></div>
                    <div class="text3">
                        <p class="medialink">Мы в соц.сетях</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttongradient3">
                        <button class="moreinf3">Подробнее</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           
        </div>
        
    </div>
   

</body>
</html>
```

[image] [image]

У меня есть такой див, который при нажатии на кнопку подробнее, должен становиться больше и становиться таким

Comment: Дополните вопрос кодом и разметкой html

Comment: дополнил код html+css

Comment: javaScript код забыли добавить

Comment: поэтому и спрашиваю, к сожалению, нет понимания, как можно реализовать это действие

Comment: либо js-ом, заменять страницы html, либо как-то js-ом, заменять один элемент другим...(

Answer (score 0):

Что бы заменить один div другим по кнопке, можно, допустим использовать свойство innerHTML. Оно хорошо подходит для статических элементов

```js
const div = document.getElementById('container');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const block1 = '<div>Первый</div>';
const block2 = '<div>Второй</div>';

let idBlock = 1;
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  idBlock++;
  div.innerHTML = idBlock % 2 ? block1 : block2;
})
div.innerHTML = block1;
```

```html
<div id="container"></div><br/>
<button id="btn">Сменить</button>
```

Если надо менять html элементы, которые обладают своими собственными событиями, то их надо сначала поместить в переменную(в коде ниже, создается кнопка из функции)

```js
const btnContainer = document.getElementById('buttons');
const add = document.getElementById('addBtn');
let buttonNumber = 1;

function buildButton() {
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  const name = buttonNumber++;
  button.innerText = name;
  button.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('click', name))
  return button;
}
let prev = buildButton()
add.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const newBtn = buildButton()
  btnContainer.replaceChild(newBtn, prev)
  prev = newBtn;
})
btnContainer.appendChild(prev)
```

```html
<div id="buttons"></div>
<button id="addBtn">Сменить кнопку</button>
```